# Oracle sp cannot use Count with data integer

Tags: oracle, plsql

this sp was written for SQL Server and then 'converted ' for use in Oracle. but the app is It's failing due to the data type returned by Oracle and MSSQL is different.
How can I adjust this sp to return data acceptable to Oracle?

```
DECLARE
  CNT PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO CNT
    FROM OEN.DBD_C_MODULES;

  IF CNT > 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO OEN.DBD_C_MODULES (MODULE_ID, DESCRIPTION, ACTIVE) VALUES (11, 'Medi', 1);
    INSERT INTO OEN.DBD_C_MODULES (MODULE_ID, DESCRIPTION, ACTIVE) VALUES (15, 'Orde', 1);
    COMMIT;
  END IF;
END;

/


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OEN.DBD_GET_MEDICINE (
  FACILITYKEY VARCHAR2
, DATEFROM DATE
, DATETHRU DATE
, UNITSTR VARCHAR2
, INCLUDEDISCH NUMERIC
, PATNUMBER NUMERIC
, MEDNAME VARCHAR2
, OCURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN OCURSOR FOR
    SELECT DTR.DATE_ORDER "Date"
         , COUNT(*) "Count"
      FROM ( ( ( ( (
                    SELECT TRUNC(DATEFROM) + ROWNUM DATE_ORDER, ROWNUM + 1 DAY_ORDER FROM OEN.GEN_C_DX WHERE ROWNUM <= DATETHRU - DATEFROM
                   ) DTR
                   INNER JOIN OPTC.ORD_M_ADMIN AM ON DTR.DATE_ORDER + ( AM.ADMIN_TIME - TRUNC(AM.ADMIN_TIME) ) BETWEEN AM.START_DATE AND AM.END_DATE
                 )
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN OPTC.ORD_D_ADMIN_LOG AL ON AM.ORDER_KEY = AL.ORDER_KEY 
               )
               LEFT OUTER JOIN OPTC.ORD_C_ADMIN_RESULT AR ON AL.ADMIN_RESULT = AR.RESULT_KEY
             )
             INNER JOIN OGEN.GEN_M_PATIENT_MAST M ON AM.PAT_NUMBER = M.PAT_NUMBER AND AM.FACILITY_KEY = M.FACILITY_KEY AND ( UNITSTR IS NULL OR MOD(INSTR(UNITSTR, M.UNIT_CODE), 2) = 1 )
           )
           LEFT OUTER JOIN OGEN.GEN_M_DOCTOR_MAST DR ON M.PRIMARY_DOCTOR_KEY = DR.DOCTOR_KEY AND M.FACILITY_KEY = DR.FACILITY_KEY 
     WHERE AM.FACILITY_KEY IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(OGEN.COMMA_TO_TABLE(FACILITYKEY)))
       AND ( AM.PAT_NUMBER = PATNUMBER OR PATNUMBER = -1 )
       AND ( MEDNAME IS NULL OR AM.ORDER_NAME LIKE ( '%' || MEDNAME || '%' ) )
       AND AM.PRN = 0
       AND OPTC.ORD_IS_ADMIN(AM.START_DATE, DTR.DATE_ORDER, AM.DAYS_REQ) = 1
       AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT AL1.ORDER_KEY
                          FROM OPTC.ORD_D_ADMIN_LOG AL1 
                         WHERE AL1.ORDER_KEY = AM.ORDER_KEY
                           AND INSTR('01234', CAST(ABS(AL1.ADMIN_RESULT) AS VARCHAR2(2))) > 0 )
       AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT OM.ORDER_KEY
                          FROM OPC.ORD_M_ORDER OM
                         WHERE OM.ORDER_STATUS = 0
                           AND OM.HOLD_ON_FROM = AM.ORDER_KEY
                           AND DTR.DATE_ORDER BETWEEN OM.START_DATE AND OM.END_DATE )
       AND ( ( INCLUDEDISCH = 0 ) OR ( 1 = ( CASE WHEN ( INCLUDEDISCH = 1 ) AND M.DISCHARGE_DATE IS NULL THEN 1 WHEN ( INCLUDEDISCH = 2 ) AND ( M.DISCHARGE_DATE IS NOT NULL ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) ) )
      GROUP BY DTR.DATE_ORDER;
END;
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what is failing?  Are you getting an Oracle error?  If so, what error?  What line?  Is it a compilation error?  Or a runtime error?  If you know it is a data type error, what column is the problem?  What data type does the application expect?

Comment: There are two counts. Which gives the error? Also, how are those two blocks of code related? The procedure is not used in the anonymous plsql block.

Comment: I think `pls_integer` should just be `integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input parameters defined as `NUMERIC` should be `NUMBER` eg:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OEN.DBD_GET_MEDICINE (
  FACILITYKEY  IN  VARCHAR2,
  DATEFROM     IN  DATE,
  DATETHRU     IN  DATE,
  UNITSTR      IN  VARCHAR2,
  INCLUDEDISCH IN  NUMBER,
  PATNUMBER    IN  NUMBER,
  MEDNAME      IN  VARCHAR2,
  OCURSOR      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
```

Comment: no its ok now, thank you for your kind assistance. God bless you.